# Agreagar setinterval a row datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables, setinterval

Como podria integrar un setinterval de 1 seg a esto:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="listado" class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>N° PROCESO</th>
   <th>TECNICO</th>
   <th>FECHA ENT. INTERNA</th>
   <th>PROCESO</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#listado').DataTable({
"ajax":{
  "method":"GET",
  "data": {idped: <?php echo $idped?>, etp : <?php echo $etapa?>, folio : <?php echo $fol?>},
  "url" : url.php',
},
"columns" : [
{
          "sClass": "alignRight",
          "data" : "folio"
        },{
          "sClass": "alignRight",
          'data' : null,
           'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
            var nom = row['nombres'];
            var ape = row['apellidos'];
            return ''+nom+'&nbsp;'+ape+'';
           }
        },{
      <!-------- AQUI NECESITO EL SETINTERVAL --------->
        "sClass": "alignRight",
        "data" : "fecha_tope",
        "render": function (data) {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
            return moment(now).countdown(data).toString();
         }
       <!--------------------------------------------------->
        },{
        "sClass": "alignRight",
        "data" : "nom_etapa"
        }
      ],

      "order": [
        [0, 'asc']
      ],
      "iDisplayLength": 25,
      "language": {
          "emptyTable": "SIN REGISTROS",
          "infoEmpty": "",
          "search": "Buscar _INPUT_ ",
          "info": "Mostrando Pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
          "lengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ Registros",
          "infoFiltered": "(Busqueda Desde _MAX_ Registros Totales)",
          "paginate": {
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous": "Anterior"
          }
      },

    });
```

});


el codigo hace un countdown con moment.js y me lo muestra en dias, horas, minutos y segundos, pero necesito que se actualice cada 1 seg solo ese row y no tabla completa para que parezca un reloj contador hacia atras (count down).
Alguna idea? Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Si no pones ningún código de tu tabla creo que nadie te podrá ayudar

Comment: @abrahamhs no veo la necesidad de poner mas codigo. lo que puse ahi, es un reloj contador que se genera a traves de moment.js, countdown.js y moment-countdown.js. lo que necesito es solo ver la posibilidad de integrar un set interval en ese row. saludos

Comment: pregunta necesitas que el setInterval este en cada fila o solo en una en especifico??

Comment: @abrahamhs lo ideal seria poner el setinterval en el row que esta comentado, porque es ahi donde debe ir el countdown. Cabe señalar que la tabla es dinamica y puede contener uno o mas registros. Saludos y gracias por cualquier ayuda u orientacion al respecto.

Comment: Es que creo que estas confundido, lo que comentaste es una celda (un td), ya que un row lo representa toda la definición de columns, no una sección entre llaves. Una sección entre llaves es un td (una celda) no un row (tr).

Comment: @abrahamhs perdon, tienes razon, error de conceptos.. pero es lo que dices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu html debes colocar un id a esa celda para poder seleccionarla:

```
<td><span id='demo' class="changemade"></span></td>
```

Luego en el datatables inicializar esa celda:

```
"render": function (data) {
       return  new Date().getTime();  
 }
```

Por ultimo en el ready levantas el interval y en cada ejecucion exploras todas las filas y haces el calculo en cada celda:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
idInterval=setInterval(function(){
    table.column( 0 ).data().each( function ( value, index ) {
            var valor = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
            var x = moment(valor).subtract(1, 'seconds');//Resto el segundo
            $(".changemade").html(x._d);
            //Estas dos actualizan el datatables
            var UpdateTD = $(".changemade").parent('td');
            table.cell( UpdateTD ).data( UpdateTD.html()).draw();
        } );
}, 1000);    
$( '.changebutton' ).on( 'click', function () {
    clearInterval(idInterval);
}); 
});
```

Agregue un botón para detener el `setInterval`.
Si usas un `class` la función each no tiene sentido pero todas las celdas tendrán el mismo valor. Si usas `id` todas las celdas tendrán su propio valor pero tienes que usar each. https://jsfiddle.net/jx4ywfk9/

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias por tu ayuda y orientacion. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

esto más o menos seria lo que necesitas, pero si quieres cancelarlo debes guardar el `setInterval` en una variable.

```
"render": function (data) {
       var now = new Date().getTime();
       return setInterval(function(){
          return moment(now).countdown(data).toString();
       }, 1000);
     }
```

Comment: hola estimado, gracias por tu respuesta, pero no funciona, no me muestra nada en ese row y tampoco da error. Alguna idea del porque? Saludos y gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Hola, olvide agregar un return, podrias revisarlo de nuevo ?

Comment: agregue tu modificacion, pero ahora me imprime 4 y 5 en los lugares donde deberian ir los dias, minutos y segundos en retroceso. Vi el json y al parecer esos 4 y 5 son los indices de otros datos que vienen en la cadena json y no las fechas datetime correspondientes. Mencionar que tampoco dar error de ningun tipo.

Comment: es verdad data debe perder persistencia, entonces si es necesario colocar el resto del codigo para saber que dato esta ingresandose, o de plano crea un https://codesanbox.io

Comment: acabo de editar la pregunta y puse la tabla completa. Si necesitas algo mas, con gusto respondere a la brevedad. Saludos y muchas gracias por todo.